# SQLAlchemy ошибка выборки

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Если делаю такую выборку в FastApi:

```
data = con.execute(
        f"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME").fetchall()
```

то выборку вижу.

А если так:

```
data = con.execute(
        f"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME as tn WHERE tn.field1 LIKE '%моя%' or tn.field2 LIKE '%моя%'").fetchall()
```

то выскакивает ошибка:

> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)

В документации об этом написано:

> Исключение, вызванное ошибками программирования, например, таблица не найдена или уже существует, синтаксическая ошибка в инструкции SQL, неверное количество заданных параметров и т. Д.

Я что-то понять не могу в чем ошибка? Я же ведь проверил этот запрос в DataGrid - и он там прекрасно отработал, почему тут не хочет отрабатывать?

Comment: Возможно, проблема связана с количеством параметров, которые привязываются. Попробуйте заменить Ваш запрос на `(
    "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME as tn WHERE tn.field1 LIKE :search or tn.field2 LIKE :search", 
    {"search": "%моя%"}
)`.

Comment: Я ссылался на [эту документацию](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/docs/sqlalchemy.orm.Session.execute). Если тот вариант не поможет, может там найдете нужный ответ.

Comment: Увы, но не помогло..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-общем, если кто-то столкнется с похожей проблемой, то вот как я ее решил (запрос отправлять через **text()**):

```
from sqlalchemy import text
data = con.execute(text(f"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME as tn WHERE tn.field1 LIKE '%моя%' or tn.field2 LIKE '%моя%'")).fetchall()
```